# How to display controllers and actions from list in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I iterate in all restricted controller and their associated action and add those controller and action in my class.

```
public class ControllerActionList
{
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }        
}
```

This way I populate by hand for simulation purposes:

```
public List<ControllerActionList> ControllerActionList()
{
    List<ControllerActionList> oControllerActionList = new List<ControllerActionList>
    {
        new ControllerActionList { ControllerName = "Home", ActionName = "Index" },
        new ControllerActionList { ControllerName = "Home", ActionName = "DashBoard" },
        new ControllerActionList { ControllerName = "Home", ActionName = "Chart" },

        new ControllerActionList { ControllerName = "HR", ActionName = "Leave" },
        new ControllerActionList { ControllerName = "HR", ActionName = "Loan" },
        new ControllerActionList { ControllerName = "HR", ActionName = "NoticeBoard" },

        new ControllerActionList { ControllerName = "PayRoll", ActionName = "View" },
        new ControllerActionList { ControllerName = "PayRoll", ActionName = "Edit" },
        new ControllerActionList { ControllerName = "PayRoll", ActionName = "Process" }
    };

    return oControllerActionList;
}
```

Now what logic should I use to display those controllers and their associated action names in my view (see images below)?

See, the controller names are **Home, HR and Payroll** and actions are shown below.

Could you tell me the best way to display controller name first as a header and below their action names. In my case, the controller name is repeated in class.

One thing I can do is that I can write a for-loop and when controller name changes, I will create a new `div` where a new or next controller name will be shown.

Also please give me hints on how to implement this design via [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap).

My questions now are:

1) How to show a controller name at top and its associated actions below in a `div` and repeat that action for each controller?

2) How to achieve the shown design with bootstrap?

[image]

Comment: Use GroupBy on  ControllerName and then you can iterate based on that and flatten the action names

Comment: i am not sure how to use group by on controller name because i need to get all action name of each controller. can u provide a sample just for hint to use group by on controller name.

Comment: Linq GroupBy is well documented

Comment: BTW To avoid confusion you should rename *ControllerActionList* to *ControllerActionItem* or just *ControllerAction*

Comment: can u tell me how to achieve the above design with bootstrap? how to create separate div for each controller and action with bootstrap ? give me some hint.

Comment: Is the expected output used inside a form with checkboxes you send back to controller?

Comment: see @Janes answer. he gave me nice hint with a sample code.

Comment: I already saw that answer (as you can see by my comment on it). But MVC can do that much better especially with input forms

Comment: u said "But MVC can do that much better especially with input forms" not clear. please come with a example what u said.

Comment: That would only fit if you want to show an input form with checkboxes. I already asked about it and you did not clearify. If then search for "asp.net mvc editorfor collection" with your favorite search engine. You will find tons of results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've majorly rewritten this answer, take a look at the change history if you want to see the old and bad one.

As you've seen in the comments, the majority said you have to use `.GroupBy` to get the single `ControllerActionItems`. I've rewritten this into two classes now, one class called `ControllerBlock` and one `ControllerAction`.

**ControllerBlock** (now has a 1-n-relationship with `ControllerAction`):

```
public class ControllerBlock
{
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public List<ControllerAction> ControllerActions { get; set; }
}
```

**ControllerAction:**

```
public class ControllerAction
{
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public bool ActionActive { get; set; }
}
```

Under the assumption that those rectangles are indeed `CheckBox` controls, you can use a so called Editor Template to reduce code and minimify trouble in your `Controller`.

Depending on where you want to use the code, you can put it into `Views` -> `Shared` -> `EditorTemplates`.

Now create a View that's exactly named after your Model, here: `ControllerBlock`

[image: EditorTemplate structure in solution]

Open the `ControllerBlock.cshtml` file and reference the model via `@model ControllerBlock`, then build your [html](/questions/tagged/html):

```
@model ControllerBlock

<div class="col-lg-12 panel">
    @Model.ControllerName
    <hr class="row">
    @foreach (ControllerAction actionItem in Model.ControllerActions)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-4">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => actionItem.ActionActive)<a href="~/@Model.ControllerName/@actionItem.ActionName">@actionItem.ActionName</a></div>
    }
</div>
```

Now you can build your site models easily on top of that.

In the respective site views, use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ControllerActionBlocks)` to reference that Editor Template. ASP.NET will automatically take care of the rest.

**SomePage.cshtml (View):**

```
@model SomeModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SomePage";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>
<h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeProperty)

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ControllerActionBlocks)
```

**Example:**

SomeModel:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ControllerBlock> ControllerActionBlocks { get; set; }
}
```

In your `Controller`, fill the model with data:

```
public IActionResult SomePage()
{
    var model = new SomeModel()
    {
        SomeProperty = "Your application model property.",
        ControllerActionBlocks = GetControllerBlocks()
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

**To do:**
Define your Editor Template for md, sm, xs devices.

For more info about columns on bootstrap, visit [Bootstrap Grid System](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

This is definition of `GetControllerBlocks()`:

```
public List<ControllerBlock> GetControllerBlocks()
{
    //Set ActionActive herem, if necessary
    List<ControllerAction> homeActions = new List<ControllerAction>() {
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Index" },
        new ControllerAction {  ActionName = "DashBoard" },
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Chart" }
    };
    List<ControllerAction> hrActions = new List<ControllerAction>() {
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Leave" },
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Loan" },
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "NoticeBoard" }
        };

    List<ControllerAction> payRollActions = new List<ControllerAction>() {
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "View" },
        new ControllerAction {  ActionName = "Edit" },
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Process" }
        };

    List<ControllerBlock> actionBlocks = new List<ControllerBlock>()
    {
        new ControllerBlock(){ControllerName = "Home", ControllerActions = homeActions},
        new ControllerBlock(){ControllerName = "HR",  ControllerActions =  hrActions},
        new ControllerBlock(){ControllerName = "PayRoll",  ControllerActions =  payRollActions}
    };

    return actionBlocks;
}
```

Comment: your new code is fine but one request that please add your old code also what you posted before if possible. thanks a lot.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar You can click "edited n hours" ago, beside my username. Scroll down to the bottom, you'll find it there.